# Date format :DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I know Current Date function gives mig date for Today CURRENT DATE ='2022-06-29'
If I want to get the First date and Last date to current month how I can do it in DB2?

```
cast(JOB.FOMDATE as DATE), cast(JOB.TOMDATE as DATE)) OVERLAPS (cast(***'2022-01-01'*** as DATE), cast(***'2022-01-31'*** as DATE))
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Could you go over question and edit it to make it readable? Also add which Db2 version and platform.

Comment: The title of the question is absolutely non-relevant, if you really want to get first and last dates of month of a given date.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following built-in functions:
[FIRST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-first-day)
[LAST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-last-day)

```
SELECT 
  D
, FIRST_DAY (D)                     AS D_FIRST
, D - DAY (D) + 1                   AS D_FIRST_ALT
, LAST_DAY (D)                      AS D_LAST
, D - (DAY (D) - 1) + 1 MONTH - 1   AS D_LAST_ALT
FROM (VALUES CURRENT DATE) T (D)
```